# How to download all QGIS plugins?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Does anyone have any idea how I could download all QGIS plugins without having to do that from the interface one by one (possible but tedious).

I am doing this for a friend who uses an offline computer, I'd like to send him a USB drive with the new version of QGIS and the plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Not using the interface no, however you can write a Python script to do it which I have done in a project of [mine](https://github.com/NathanW2/qgis_plugins_analysis/blob/master/analysis.py).

Here is a an extract:

```
def get_plugins(qgisversion='2.4'):
    """
    Fetch the plugins from plugin repo
    :return: name, url, filename
    """
    plugin_request = requests.get("http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml?qgis={}".format(qgisversion))
    xml = minidom.parseString(plugin_request.text)
    plugins = xml.getElementsByTagName("pyqgis_plugin")
    for plugin in plugins:
        name = plugin.attributes["name"].value
        url = plugin.getElementsByTagName("download_url")[0].childNodes[0].data
        filename = plugin.getElementsByTagName("file_name")[0].childNodes[0].data
        yield name, url, filename

for name, url, filename in get_plugins():
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

This requires requests to be installed (`pip install requests` if you don't have it), and will run in a normal Python install. Doesn't have to be run inside QGIS.

The main QGIS plugin site provides a xml document with all the plugins, their names, and download URLs, we just download that, pull out the info and download the file.